# What is the form of my local postgresql database url?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am going through a flask/sqlalchemy tutorial 
https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html#a-minimal-application
and I configured my database url to be:
postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/dbname

when I run db.create_all() in the interactive python shell it doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't do anything either.

From what I understand it is supposed to create the User table with three columns; id, username, and email .

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template 
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/dbname'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

app.debug = True



@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('hello.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Which driver are you using? The driver [isn't always optional](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/config.html#connection-uri-format).

Comment: @SpencerCooley Can you post your `psql` query, before that Have you done `create_db()`

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#database-urls

Answer (score 18):

It should be the exact format.

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql://username:password@localhost:port/DBNAME"
```

Comment: Although `'postgresql:///DBNAME'` works if you are connecting locally over a Unix domain socket.

Answer (score 1):

Once you install PostgreSQL you can do this:

```py
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql://<username>:<password>@localhost/<database_name>"
```

Where:

- `<username>` is your username (by default `postgres`)
- `<password>` is your password (by default `postgres`)
- `<database_name>` the name of your database (by deafault `postgres` if you are using the DB created once you installed PostgreSQL).

If you have created a role (a user) for example `admin` with password `admin` and a database named `posts` then you can do this:

```py
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql://admin:admin@localhost/posts"
```

more info here https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `postgresql` in the *URL* instead of `postgres`.

That's the form that's used both for *JDBC* and in the *SQLAlchemy* doc (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/postgresql.html).

Comment: Yes, I did try that, but then I go in to the psql console and check to see if any new tables were created and don't see anything.

Comment: Hmm... so you can connect with those same params via *psql*... Anything in the *postgres* log?

Comment: need to check that. I am using postgres.app on mac os, not sure if that makes some sort of difference. Just found this link http://codeinthehole.com/writing/configuring-logging-for-postgresapp/

Comment: Ah. Yeah it looks like from that link logging isn't enabled by default. I use Postgres on Ubuntu, usually compiled from source, so I'm not familiar with *postgres.app* specifically. It essentially seems to be a boxed-up version of Postgres with a few add-ons.

Comment: Spencer Cooley - you have to commit in python to make the changes really happen (autocommit should be off by default)

Comment: As of [v1.4.0b](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/changelog_14.html#change-3687655465c25a39b968b4f5f6e9170b) `postgresql[+driver]://...` is required.  The `postgres[+driver]://...` form is no longer supported by SQLAlchemy.