# connecting to database using sqlalchemy using DATABASE_URL

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am comfortable in using SQL query languages and need to develop a web application.
I am learning python -sqlachemy and stuck in get connected to postgressql database.

Please let me know:
what are the libraries i need to install ?
How do i Configure DATABASE_URL in flask.[enter image description here][1]

I am stuck with code line no-6.
I need to know how to get DATABASE_URL configured? I am very new potgressql.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oGRC.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the form of my local postgresql database url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727902/what-is-the-form-of-my-local-postgresql-database-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up in bash or you can use `dotenv` package from `pypi`:

```
$ export DATABASE_URL=postgresql://username:password@host:port/dbname
```

If your `username=blue`, `password=pass`, `host=localhost`, and `port=5432`, `dbname=testDB` then:

```
$ export DATABASE_URL=postgresql://blue:pass@localhost:5432/testDB
```

To check if the postgres db is running-- or check the port on which it is running:

```
$ sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep LISTEN
```

Comment: Sorry for not giving complete information. I am using windows and preffer to keep the database details - username, password, dbname etc in windows environment variable or python configuraion file instead of hardcideing. I am confortable in SQL Language and preffer to write SQL Queries and creat tables and maintain database form pgadmin/backend.

Comment: Use the same definition either in windows environment variable which you do using SET or in python configuration file. `DATABASE_URL=postgresql://username:password@host:port/dbname`

Comment: Try hardcoding the value first, then move it outside to the env/config file